# WebBrowser control doesn't open links

Tags: wpf, windows, internet-explorer

I'm using the default `WebBrowser` control inside a WPF application. HTML code is loaded using `NavigateToString` method (`html` is passed as a parameter).

Pages render correctly, but users aren't able to click on any links (nothing happens when they click on the links). The problem was partly solved by adding the URLs to trusted zone, but that is not always possible.

Are there any configurations that should be adjusted in IE (or wherever else) that would allow opening any links inside an embedded `WebBrowser`?

Answer (score 0):

in my case using `MyWebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(...));` works, and hyperlinks work as designed but when i use `MyWebBrowser.NavigateToString(htmlContent);` hyperlinks stop working